# How to get hyperlinked references?

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf

I'm trying to embed references to my Works Cited into the text of a research paper, as though they were hyperlinks on the authors' names who I am cited throughout the document. For instance, if I wanted to mention the authors "Kruger et. al (2008)", I would like the reader to be able to click on the author's name and have it redirect them to the end of the document where my references would be.

Comment: What happens when you just add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to  your document, just before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Most citation/bibliography packages in the LaTeX world interface with `hyperref`, so usually this should 'just work' if you load `\usepackage{hyperref}` in your preamble. If it doesn't work, you need to tell us more about your specific setup and how you generate citations and your bibliography. This is best done in a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), a short example document that contains just the code needed to reproduce the relevant bits of what you are seeing at the moment.